# Issues with rmarkdown in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I get the following error when i start R-studio and also whenever I install a new package:

```
Error: invalid version specification ‘NA’
In addition: Warning message:
In utils:::packageDescription(packageName, fields = "Version") :
  no package 'knitr' was found
```

I am on a computer without admin rights (work computer) with windows 10. R-studio (v. 3.4.2) is installed on C:/Program Files/RStudio. I have tried most of the things listed [here](http://Error:%20invalid%20version%20specification%20%E2%80%98NA%E2%80%99%20In%20addition:%20Warning%20message:%20In%20utils:::packageDescription(packageName,%20fields%20=%20%22Version%22)%20:%20%20%20no%20package%20'knitr'%20was%20found), but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I have two lib paths:

```
[1] "\\\\something/something/_users/something/something/R/RLib"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.2/library"
```

I changed the main lib path to number 1 above recently (however these problems were there before that also) and tried to install all packages there (since i cannot do that in C:, no admin rights). Installing f.ex tidyverse there works fine, and also all other packages I have tried.

I tried to install the rmarkdown package normally with:

```
install.packages("rmarkdown")
```

and also by:

```
devtools::install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rmarkdown_1.6.tar.gz")
```

and also:

```
install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com")
```

I also tried to change the repo:

```
options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com"))
```

And lastly, I tried installing every package needed manually by install.packages(). That did not change anything either.

All of the above did not work. I have tried to tick all the necessary packages in the "packages" menu in R-studio, but when i try to knit my rmarkdown document it still wants to install updated versions of one or more packages. This happens over and over.

Also, I tried to change lib path by user variable:

```
Variable name: R_LIBS_USER 
Variable value: C:FOLDER_LOCATION
```

Is it maybe because I have two different library locations? I cannot seem to remove the lib path number 2, as that is the default library path (?).

Any suggestions?

Edit:

```
Sessioninfo():

R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.1252  LC_CTYPE=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                            
[5] LC_TIME=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 tools_3.4.2  


.libPaths():
Same as mentioned earlier.
```

Comment: Please add the output of `sessionInfo()` and `.libPaths()` (all paths - if they are different from the paths already mentioned in your question) to your question to get more insights

Comment: Just added them now!

Comment: It is almost impossible to diagnose installation issues "remotely" (e. g. the pre-installed packages may be write protected but need an update to install another package). Once I had similar problems (no admin rights) and solved it by installing base R and RStudio myself into the C:\Users\Public folder which is always writeable and a better location than a remote network drive. R and RStudio do not need to have admin rights to be installed. Just download the ZIP file version of RStudio and unzip it into above folder.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? If yes please share it here :-)

Comment: I reinstalled everything (both R and R-studio) in a folder with full rights and it solved the problem. Seems like it sometimes could save packages and sometimes not when saved in the earlier folder.

Comment: @Haakonkas Shouldn't this be an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled everything (both R and R-studio) in a folder with full rights and it solved the problem. Seems like it sometimes could save packages and sometimes not when saved in the earlier folder